# Hide AppBarLayout using toolbar in fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, toolbar

This is my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

This is my some part of MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Fragment fragment,recepie_fragment,products_fragment,swadeshi_fragment,previous;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yash);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(null);
  //  final View ab=(View)findViewById(R.id.appbarmain);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    recepie_fragment=new Recepie_Fragment();

    products_fragment=new Products_Fragment();
    swadeshi_fragment=new Swadeshi_Fragment();
    fragment=recepie_fragment;//new Fragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bglayout,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    previous=fragment;
    BottomBar bb=BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
    bb.setActiveTabColor("RED");

    bb.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_buttons, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int menuItemId) {
            fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            switch(menuItemId)
            {
                case R.id.button1:
                    previous=fragment;
                   // ab.setAlpha(0);
                    fragment=recepie_fragment;//new Recepie_Fragment();
                   // fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    //getSupportActionBar().show();
                    previous=fragment;
                    fragment=products_fragment;//new Products_Fragment();
                    //fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    previous=fragment;
                    //getSupportActionBar().show();
                    fragment=swadeshi_fragment;//new Swadeshi_Fragment();
                    //fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

                    break;
            }
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bglayout,fragment);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my RecepieFragment.java

```
public class Recepie_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    int logo_ids[]={R.drawable.main_course,R.drawable.cakes,R.drawable.specials};
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    void setupTabIcons()
    {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(logo_ids[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(logo_ids[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.extra);
       // tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView();

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //getActivity().getApplication().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recepie_viewpager, container, false);
        //getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yash);
       // ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yash).animate().translationY(-(R.id.toolbar_yash).getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();

        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView. findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                //actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            private int previousState, currentState;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();       //ViewPager Type
                if (currentPage == 2 || currentPage == 0) {
                    previousState = currentState;
                    currentState = state;
                    if (previousState == 1 && currentState == 0) {

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? 2 : 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());//(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Main_Course(), "");
        adapter.addFrag(new Cakes(), "");
        adapter.addFrag(new Specials(), "");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And this the xml file i am using :

```
tools:context=".activity.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbarmain"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_yash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below type of visualisation is created when I'm trying to hide the toolbar/actionbar in recepies fragment. What I want is whenever I move into products or swadeshi fragment I get this action bar but when in recepie fragment my actionbar hides and screen consists of my viewpager of 3 elements as shown of cake but instead a blank is created.

[image]

Comment: (Slightly off topic, but you are misspelling **recipe** - English can be non-intuitive sometimes).

Comment: Are you asking about the Toolbar, AppBarLayout, or the TabLayout? It's not clear what you do want it to look like and when

Comment: updated the question with the xml file. I am asking about toolbar used as AppBarLayout

Comment: Do you solve the problem? @YashAgrawal

Comment: Yes i did @inverted_index